# cannot navigate on the history of iframe content

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser-history

I am using iframe to load second web site in my program.

I created for this purpose div with iframe inside :

```
<div id='ktmv-help'>
    <iframe id="contextHelp" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

I am using `$('#contextHelp')[0].contentWindow.location.replace(url);` command to change programmatically content of iframe when I navigate between pages of my program.

The problem is I cannot go back on previos page of my iframe after changing content by `$('#contextHelp')[0].contentWindow.location.replace(url);` command.

I tried `history.back()`, `window.history.back()`, `history.go(-1)` commands but all of them don't work. I see same iframe page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs:

> ## Cross-origin script API access
>
> JavaScript APIs like [iframe.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow), `window.parent`, `window.open`, and `window.opener` allow documents to directly reference each other. **When two documents do not have the same origin,** these references provide **very limited access** to Window and Location objects, as described in the next two sections.
>
> Specification: [HTML Living Standard § Cross-origin objects](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#cross-origin-objects).

For more information, see

- [MDN Web Security Reference - Same Origin Policy - Cross-origin script API Access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access)